# Javascript functional library with persistent data structures

Tags: data-structures, functional-programming, javascript, persistent-data

I'm looking for a functional library with persistent data structures.  I only need nested arrays and dictionaries.  There are some [functional javascript libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3690411/which-javascript-functional-library-underscore-or-wu-js-or-functional-or), but they are not geared towards immutability.  I want to be able to write

```
var dict = makeDictionary({
  'foo': 1;
  'bar': {
     'ely': 2;
  }
});
var newDict = dict.assoc('foo', 42).assoc('bar', 'tender', 30).dissoc('bar', 'ely');
assert.eq dict.bar.ely, 2; // unchanged
assert.eq newDict.bar.tender, 30; // added
assert.eq newDict.bar.ely, undefined; // removed
```

While [underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/) comes close in some cases, especially with arrays, it modifies dictionary arguments.  I could also use [clojurescript](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript), but I'd prefer a more light-weight approach.

Comment: just to clarify (because I am currently working on something quite similar), do you need the resulting persistent map behave as a native object including "." access? That would require either simulating using getters, or copying the whole structure from the modification up and freezing it, which for big flat maps becomes inefficient quite quickly (and both require ES5)... or are you fine with functions/methods accessing the content (my approach)?

Comment: I'd be happiest with the doc-access solution, seeing its drawbacks, though. I don't have huge maps anyway. The ES5 requirement... well, I'm going to think about your function-access approach.

Comment: there is an alternative I added (to measure performance gains against naive approach). I added naive persistent map 'Nap' which does full copy-on-write. There are two variants of assoc/dissoc, but once you are done you get a native object (possibly frozen if ES5 is supported) you can access as usually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finalized my implementation of Persistent Map (and will finish Persistent Vector soon) for JavaScript, because there seems to be an increasing demand.

There are several specifics compared to e.g. Java (lack of equals, hashCode to rely on), so the implementation uses sorted balanced binary tree (balancing is actually simplified and sped up by immutability) and === for equality and < or custom function for lower-than.

the code of Feat.js (the project code name) is available at [feat-sorted-map.js at github.com](https://github.com/josef-jelinek/cofy/blob/master/lang/feat-sorted-map.js)

You can see a page with working tests in action online at [feat.js at cofylang.org](http://cofylang.org/tests/test-feat.html)

Currently, there is no documentation except the source code and tests, but I am working on finishing that as well.

**Update:** there is an implementation of a persistent vector available there as well, and the speed has been improved in orders of magnitude. (it has been cleaned-up as well) [feat-vector.js at github.com](https://github.com/josef-jelinek/cofy/blob/master/lang/feat-vector.js)

Comment: @jJ, what did you do to speed it up?

Comment: @Scott in my case I had to abandon Object.freeze, it is just unusable for its slowness (http://jsperf.com/object-freeze-performance). But other than that I used fixed-structure objects with monomorphic functions as much as possible, that is the biggest thing (for direct access, inlining etc.) IMHO. Profiler in developer tools is your best friend here.

Answer (score 9):

I'd take a look at Mori.  It packages up ClojureScript's functional data structure for use from plain old Javascript.  Since the data structures are coming from ClojureScript I'd expect them to be better tested, more complete and more performant than other libraries.

https://github.com/swannodette/mori

Answer (score 1):

There's also:

https://github.com/hughfdjackson/immutable

Which is based on the persistent hash trie algorithm here:

https://github.com/hughfdjackson/persistent-hash-trie

Might be worth looking into.

The code for this is nicer imho, but my benchmarks show it's running nearly an order of magnitude slower than the one listed above.

Answer (score 1):

The most popular and as far as I know the only one still under active development is https://immutable-js.com/

but if you want richer API then you can go with Mori as well but I'm not sure if it will be much more lightweight approach than using ClojureScript directly.